# how to mount an iso image remotely with java?

Tags: java, image, mount

does any one can help me to know if is there any method to mount an ISO image to a Remote Server at boot time using a Java application?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you mean boot from an ISO image, or just run the mount command on startup?

Comment: I need to boot from an ISO image, to install any OS to remote server, something like KVM but at the background not using the graphic interface because I need provisionig that server automatically

Comment: Is it a virtual machine?

Comment: Also, this isn't a programming question; and java will not help.

Comment: Hi, it's a real machine using IPMI protocol. On the internet I've found that there are a few GUI tools that let you mount a virtual media and were developed in Java, like NOC-PS, and some web tools like SuperMicro iKVM or IBM KVM Viewer, these tools launch a JNLP and shows a console prompt, like you were there at the server. I need to develop some tool like those but not graphic, or in case java is not the answer how can I would do that? thanks

Comment: It might be possible to netinstall with TFTP; but even [impiutil](http://ipmiutil.sourceforge.net/) doesn't seem to support booting with an ISO image. You might run it from an ISO image, but that is the inverse of what you're asking for.

Comment: yes according with IPMI specification, it doesn't support mounting a virtual media, that part is developed by vendors, but it seems very complex and I'm searching for some alternatives

Answer (score 1):

There are probably more ways to do this, but one fast way i can think of is to install something like Daemon Tools Lite, making sure to associate .iso files with this program. Once you have done this, simply have java run the iso file.

What SHOULD happen is that windows will know that Daemon Tools opens this type of file, and Daemon Tools will load with the iso already mounted!

Comment: I need to boot from an ISO image with an application in order to install any OS to a remote server, like a KVM but at the background not using the graphic interface, it needs to be an automatic process

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that. The only way Ive ever booted from an ISO is to burn it to CD/DVD and actually select it from the BIOS as the boot device. Sorry!